# UITextFieldに一番最後に入力されたキーの取得方法

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

プログラミング初心者の質問です。

環境

---

Xcode9.0.1
Swift3

---

UITextFieldに打ち込まれたキーをリアルタイムで取得したいのですが方法がわかりません。

例えば
UITextField1
UITextField2
があったとすると

ユーザーがUITtextField1に
abc
と入力したとき
UITextField2には
"a"が打たれた瞬間に"a"、"b"が打たれた瞬間に"b"が表示されるようにするにはどのようにしたらよいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITextField に入力された文字は `shouldChangeCharactersIn` で取得することができます。

参考：[UITextFieldで入力された文字の判定や、文字数、Byte数を取得する - Qiita](https://qiita.com/ShinChan/items/537b9768c15408289afa)

下記コードでやりたいことを実現できないでしょうか？

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    UITextField2.text = string
    return true
}
```

**追記**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var UITextField1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var UITextField2: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.UITextField1.delegate = self
    self.UITextField2.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: 小川様早速の回答ありがとうございます。このtextField関数の第２、３引数にはこの場合ですと、どのような値を入れれば良いのでしょうか。

Comment: このtextField関数はdelegateメソッドと呼ばれるもので、UITextFieldに文字が入力されると自動的に呼ばれます（つまり、引数に値を入れるのはあなたではありません）。`UITextField1.delegate` に self をセットすることでこのdelegateメソッドが呼ばれるようになります。回答を少し編集しました

Comment: `class ViewController: UIViewController` に `, UITextFieldDelegate` を追加するのも忘れずに